# How to fire a local notification from iWatch to be displayed on iWatch only?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, watchkit

I have read, we can fire local notifications from iWatch with support from WatchOS 3. My requirement is to display a local notification on iWatch itself and the source of the notification will be the iWatch itself.

[image]

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/BasicSupport.html

The following is the code snippets:

ExtensionDelegate

```
    @interface ExtensionDelegate () <WCSessionDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

    @end

    @implementation ExtensionDelegate


    - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching {
        // Perform any final initialization of your application.

   UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
        center.delegate = self;
        [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionSound | UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge) completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error){

        }];

        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(4 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self addALocalNotificationForState:@"This is my iWatch notification."];
        });


    }

    -(void) addALocalNotificationForState:(NSString *) message
    {
        UNMutableNotificationContent *objNotificationContent = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
        objNotificationContent.body = message;
        objNotificationContent.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
        objNotificationContent.badge = 0;

        UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger *trigger =  [UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger                                             triggerWithTimeInterval:0.1 repeats:NO];
        UNNotificationRequest *request = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:@"ten" content:objNotificationContent trigger:trigger];
        UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

        [center addNotificationRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Local Notification succeeded");
            }else{
                NSLog(@"Local Notification failed");
            }
        }];
    }
```

When I execute the above code, it works fine and I even get the log "Local Notification succeeded" but alas there is no notification on the iWatch. I tried by keeping the app both on foreground and background but for both the cases, it shows no notification.

Can somebody please help me in this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your snippet, notification is being added to center 4 sec after launch, and fires after 0.1 additional sec, and I bet that happens while app is foreground. If you'll put app background before 4 sec, app will be suspended and notificaiton will not be added. And no way you'll be able to put app background between adding and firing.

Could you try to add UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate conformance and check if `userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:` method is called?